# Modifying items in ComboBox in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a ComboBox that can display a long list of items.  There is a function on the form that needs to change the display text of these items without actually adding or removing any.  There is no data binding going on, I'm accessing the Items list directly.

The problem is, if I modify any property of the item in the Items list, it doesn't update the text in the combo box.  There is a button that can move an item from the ComboBox to another adjacent ComboBox, and when it gets moved it displays properly, so the issue seems to be it's just not redrawing it.

I've tried calling Invalidate(), Refresh(), Update(), but it doesn't work.  I suppose I could clear the ComboBox and readd everything, but this box can hold thousands of Items so I'm not sure if that's an efficient way of doing it.

Comment: Could you please add some code? Also, you say when it gets moved it displays properly. However, isnt your problem that it doesnt display properly? Maybe I missed something.

Comment: Is the combobox bound to a data source? Are the items in that data source implementing INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: Can you show 1. what type of item you're adding to the ComboBox 2. code that manages to move it successfully to another ComboBox 3. code that updates the property 4. how you're determining which property is used for display in the ComboBox

Comment: If subclassing is an option, maye this is an answer. Worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064109/dynamically-changing-the-text-of-items-in-a-winforms-combobox

Answer (score 1):

Please try simply setting the combobox text property:

```
combobox1.Text = "newText";
```

of course you still need to change the item as before.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is not possible to update the item labels without databinding. So the only thing left is to remove the according item (Items.RemoveAt) and insert it again (Items.Insert).

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following steps:

1. get the index of the item under consideration
2. get the item display text or the item itself
3. replace the item display text
4. insert the item back at the same index

here is a sample code:
(assuming your items are of *string* type)

```
int itemIndex = comboBox1.Items.IndexOf("yourItem");
string itemText = comboBox1.Items[itemIndex].ToString();
itemText = "yourNewString";
comboBox1.Items.Insert(itemIndex, itemText);
```

if the items are of other than *string* type then try the following:

```
int itemIndex = comboBox1.Items.IndexOf(/*your item*/);
var item = comboBox1.Items[itemIndex];
//type cast back to the original type
//change the display text i.e. by changing the display member inside your object
comboBox1.Items.Insert(itemIndex, item);
```

You may loop over this code snippet if your function does it for multiple items